# Getting data from a Django model inside a datetime range

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

What if I want to get the orders from 10:30 pm of DAY-1 to 9:30 of DAY? Where DAY is the chosen day.

`time_purchased = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `range` lookup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range)

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
day = datetime.now()
start_date = (day - timedelta(days=-1)).replace(hour=10, minute=30)
end_date = day.replace(hour=9, minute=30)
Model.objects.filter(time_purchased__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Just replace `day` with your value.

Comment: How will I do it if I just want them to input the date and not the time, will DateField be enough? Using Django forms

Comment: DateField will be enough, but your filters ( from 10:30 pm of DAY-1 to 9:30 of DAY) do not make sense (the time part) in conjunction with only date field.

Comment: Or you can amend only the query with `date` lookup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#date), `Model.objects.filter(time_purchased__date__range=(start_day, end_day))`

Comment: I wanted the user to only choose a date and I will return an excel file with all the items (within 10:30pm of yesterday to 9:30pm of today) in that given date